# How do I store a SQL stored procedure result that returns a row or a column value into an ASP.NET C# variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a SQL stored procedure that returns a column value (SQL data type: `nchar(1)`). The stored procedure runs and comes back with desired value when a parameter is passed. Based on this returned value, I want to divert the program flow. For this I need to read the value returned in an ASP.NET C# variable, but I am not sure how can I do this.

```
create procedure sproc_Type
      @name as nchar(10)
AS    
SELECT Type FROM Table WHERE Name = @name
```

I want to read `Type` value in .cs file and want to save it for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             SqlConnection conn = null;
             SqlDataReader rdr  = null;
             conn = new 
                SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            // 1.  create a command object identifying
            //     the stored procedure
            SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(
                "Stored_PROCEDURE_NAME", conn);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows
            //    to execute a stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // 3. add parameter to command, which
            //    will be passed to the stored procedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@PARAMETER_NAME", PARAMETER_VALUE));

            // execute the command
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // iterate through results, printing each to console
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                var result = rdr["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for replies guys, byt I was specifically looking for code that I have to write inside while loop

Comment: var result = rdr["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString = "(your connection string here)";
string commandText = "usp_YourStoredProc";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
// your code to fetch here.
}
conn.Close();

}
```